# How to insert and update queue for particular key in CHM in an atomic way?

Tags: java, multithreading, thread-safety

I am working with Java 7. I have a `ConcurrentHashMap` wrapped around `AtomicReference` in a class which is being populated by multiple threads as shown below:

```
  private final AtomicReference<ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Holder>>> channelByHolderReference =
        new AtomicReference<>(new ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Holder>>());

 // below method will be called by multiple threads to populate and update the map
 // is below method thread safe and I won't loose any update?
  public void add(final Channel channel, final Holder holder) {
    ConcurrentMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Holder>> holderByChannel =
        channelByHolderReference.get();
    ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Holder> messageHolder = holderByChannel.get(channel);
    if (messageHolder == null) {
      messageHolder = Queues.newConcurrentLinkedQueue();
      ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Holder> currentMessageHolder =
          holderByChannel.putIfAbsent(channel, messageHolder);
      if (currentMessageHolder != null)
        messageHolder = currentMessageHolder;
    }
    messageHolder.add(holder);
  }

  // called only by single background thread every 30 seconds
  public void send() {
    ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Holder>> holderByChannel =
        channelByHolderReference
            .getAndSet(new ConcurrentHashMap<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Holder>>());
    for (Entry<Channel, ConcurrentLinkedQueue<Holder>> entry : holderByChannel
        .entrySet()) {
            // now iterate the map and do some processing
        }
  }
```

For each `Channel` I will have multiple `Holder` objects so that is why I have a `Queue` of `Holder` object for each channel. Here `Channel` is an enum in my code.

My above `add` method will be called by multiple threads and then I have another method `send` in the same class which will only be called by single background thread only every few seconds. So whatever I have in that map, I will send it (by calling send method) every 30 seconds from a single background thread.

My question is - Is my `add` method thread safe in the way I am populating and updating my map for multiple `holder` object for each channels? Do I need `AtomicReference` here because as per my understanding CHM is already synchronized so I might not need it?

Comment: Please see http://codereview.stackexchange.com/q/154566/50505

Comment: It’s actually possible to lose messages with that design.

Comment: @Holger In which part of code, I will loose messages? Can you explain? Am I doing anything wrong? I think it's a double checked locking approach in Java7 as I cannot use `computeIfAbsent` as of now.

Comment: Within `send()`, you are replacing the map with a new map. At this time, there might be a thread (or even multiple threads) still working with the old map in `add` and there is no guaranty that the loop in `send()` runs slow enough to see all these updates. When `send()` exits, there might be still threads not having completed their `add` operation on the old map.

Comment: hmmm I see what you mean.. So should I sleep for some period after `getAndSet` line (which I  know it's not a good idea) or there is any better approach by which I won't loose any data?